# iphone; when to release a view when multiple copies are derived from it?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uiview

This is my scenario
I have a main view, in which multiple copies of a subview are created.
This is how i am doing it
1. In the main view, i have created a variable for the subview
2. created multiple copies of the subview and displayed them inside a scrollable view which works fine
3. When will be the right time to release the subview variable?

Subview declaration
SubView *svm;

```
svm=[[SubView alloc] initWithNib:@"SubView" bundle:nil]
//Show svm here
// am not releasing svm here
svm=[[SubView alloc] initWithNib:@"SubView" bundle:nil]
//Show svm here
// am not releasing svm here
svm=[[SubView alloc] initWithNib:@"SubView" bundle:nil]
//Show svm here
// am not releasing svm here
```

I am not sure if that's the right way, but it works well.

If i release svm in the mainview's dealloc, will that be fine? How should i go about this?

Thanks
Veeru

Answer (score 1):

Every time you alloc a new memory gets allocated for the new instance. to prevent memory leaks you should release before creating a new instance.

```
svm=[[SubView alloc] initWithNib:@"SubView" bundle:nil]
//Show svm here
[svm release];

svm=[[SubView alloc] initWithNib:@"SubView" bundle:nil]
//Show svm here

[svm release];
svm=[[SubView alloc] initWithNib:@"SubView" bundle:nil]
//Show svm here
[svm release];
```

BTW when you add your svm as a subview into another view it gets retained by it's super view and you can safely release if it's no longer needed to be accessed directly by your code.

Comment: but if i release, the app crashes on any operations that are performed on the viewload of the subview, i presume its cause the view is being released from memory even before it finishes it operations - am i wrong?

Comment: You need to add the view to it's superview before releasing.

Comment: ofcourse, yeah i am adding it to the superview. So is it safe to releaes the view after its been added to the superview? even though there are some tasks happening when the subview is loaded/appeared?

Comment: Yes it is safe because once the view is added as a subview the super view retains it.

Comment: Interesting, but if i do that, i keep getting - message sent to deallocated instance error?!

Comment: maybe you released (or autoreleased) a single instance more than once?

Comment: hi, the scenario is - if i create a view and release it - the actions on a button inside the view leads to the "message sent to dealloc.." error.